# Why can an external hard-drive enclosure support only up to 8tB?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I am looking for a new external enclosure or a 12tB drive.

I saw this on eBay and contacted the seller, but I doubt that they can answer definitively.

I suspect that this is just an old ad image from when 8tB was the non plus ultra.

Is anyone aware of a technical reason why an enclosure would support drives of only up to 8tB?

[image]

Comment: "Is anyone aware of a technical reason why an enclosure would support drives of only up to 8tB?" - It's possible the SATA to USB controller doesn't support a disk larger than 8 TB.  Without a specification of the unit it's impossible to say.

Comment: It's likely an arbitrary size listed in the advert, as the only two things I can think of would be the enclosure's firmware _(doesn't seem likely considering it's a modern enclosure)_ or the wattage required for higher TB drives with more platters _(also doesn't seem likely, considering an 18TB 7200RPM drive pulls ~12W at most - Ohm's Law: V[olts] x A[mps] = W[atts])_